# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero

Tags: java, netbeans

Si, ya se que no se puede dividir entre cero. Pero yo quiero que me lo muestre un JOption, no que la consola me tire error. Se entiende? Debo hacer un switch que cuando el usuario indique el número el switch realice la función correspondiente. Muy básico Y ME FUNCIONA pero cuando coloco 0 en la variable n2, me tira el siguiente error

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero

```
int n1,n2,s,r,m,d,sw1;


        n1=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(" Ingrese el primer número "));
        n2=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(" Ingrese el segundo número "));
        s=n1+n2;
        r=n1-n2;
        m=n1*n2;
        d=n1/n2;

        sw1=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(" 1 SUMA, 2 RESTA, 3 MULTIPLICA Y 4 DIVIDE "));


        switch (sw1) {
        case 1:
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, " El total es "+s);
            break;

        case 2:
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, " El total es "+r);
            break;    


        case 3:    
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, " El total es "+m);

            break;    

        case 4: 

                    if (n2==0) {

                     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, " NO SE PUEDE DIVIDIR ENTRE 0 ");   

            }else{


                     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, " El total es "+d);    

                    }

            break;

           }


}
```

}

Comment: Se debe controlar al division por cero

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error es precisamente porque estas realizando una [división por cero](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisi%C3%B3n_por_cero)

La operación que causa esto es :

```
d=n1/n2;
```

considera validar el caso en que n2 tiene valor de 0, de esta forma:

```
if(n>0){
  d=n1/n2;      
}else{
  d = 0;
  n2 = 0; //* Asigna el valor para que sea mostrado por el JOptionPane.
}
```

Comment: Pero no tengo ninguna variable llamada n.

Comment: Ya lo pude resolver. Lo que hice fue agregar una variable total igualada a 0 y ya.